# Is it normal for the L298HN to produce a high Vpp when using with PWM?

Tags: motor-controller

I'm using an [L298HN](https://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/%7Emgongora/Resources/L298N.pdf) DC motor driver (ancient part, I know) as a learning exercise, but I'm not sure whether the output is as it should be.

**My L298HN schematic:**

[image: L298HN schematic]

*Edit:* There is an error in my schematic, I'm actually using FR107 recovery diodes (as that's what I had to hand) which have a 500 ns recovery time. This is above the datasheet recommended 200 ns recovery time. Could this be the problem?

When sending a solid 5V to the EnA pin, the output (OUT3, OUT4) is expected (8.6V output from 10V input), but when I use PWM on the EnA pin (500Hz; 2ms period) to control the speed of the motor, the output oscillates between +13.6V and -11.0V (24.6 Vpp). This seems it might be undesirable. I have two L298HN in two different prototypes (one breadboard, one perf board), and they both behave this way (but possibly due to it being the same schematic).

*Edit:* The motor does work when powered by the L298HN with PWM, but it sounds very different to my H-bridge prototype with PWM (the L298HN makes the motor a bit noisier, perhaps?)

**L298HN output with PWM:**

[image: L298HN output with PWM]

**L298HN output (no PWM; solid 5V)**

[image: L298HN output no PWM]

**My H-bridge schematic**

I also built my own H-bridge to deepen my understanding of how an H-bridge works, and my circuit actually works exactly how I want (a much nicer 11.8V Vpp from 10V input).

[image: H-bridge schematic]

**My H-bridge output (with PWM)**

[image: H-bridge output with PWM]

I appreciate that the L298HN might not be very efficient, and perhaps what I'm seeing is possibly normal behaviour for the IC (if so I'd be interested to know why). I plan to change my design to use a more modern IC (such as [BD6221F-E2](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2097983.pdf)) but I figured I'd make sure that I'm not just using the L298HN incorrectly.

Edit: Motor in both circuits is an [AL03S](https://www.linear-actuator.net.cn/product/linear-actuator/al03s-high-thrust-mini-linear-actuator.html).

Edit: After trying various PWM frequencies from 500Hz to 40kHz, I can't see any difference in the output (Vpp is still the same). Though, at 40kHz the motor doesn't function at all (I suppose the PWM is too high). The L298HN datasheet mentions a "commutation frequency of 25 KHz to 40 KHz." so perhaps the PWM has to be at least 25kHz? Unfortunately, my motor doesn't seem to run at this frequency, at least not when driven by the L298HN using my circuit.

Comment: How are you measuring this? 1 - There most likely is some part of the peaks that are inductive spikes, 2 - I would also bet a lot of the peaks are also radiated, not conducted (i.e. your probe, wires, perfboard, etc are antennas)

Comment: No decoupling capacitors used ?

Comment: @Antonio51 No, but I also tried with bypass caps and no effect.

Comment: @WesleyLee Both circuits are measured the same; the scope ground is connected to output 1, and the scope positive to output 2.

Comment: What kind of motor? At least, Steady current ... NB: one can't compare LM298 (2-3 A) and 14-17 A bridge with IRF530 and IRF9530 MOSFET ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Answer updated. It's a DC brushed motor. https://www.linear-actuator.net.cn/product/linear-actuator/al03s-high-thrust-mini-linear-actuator.html

Comment: @Antonio51 > "one can't compare" -- My motor draws 500mA. Are you suggesting that the LM298 might well behave this way with such a load?

Comment: Yes. But you might use PWM "slowly" because of the inrush current at starting ... until "steady" current is reached. Max current is 4A. Note the you can "paralleled" outputs for higher currents (figure 7 of data LM298N sheet).

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [L298N datasheet](https://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/%7Emgongora/Resources/L298N.pdf), I realised that there's no mention of PWM... I perhaps incorrectly assumed that PWM would work fine with this IC.

[image: Enable pins for L298N]

**Edit**

I see that while there is no mention of PWM, there is a mention of "commutation frequency" (which implies PWM).

[image: L298N commutation frequency]

On the topic of PWM, some interesting answers form another question ([L298n PWM frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309056/l298n-pwm-frequency))...

> "So if you have brushed DC motors then I would recommend a PWM frequency of 2 kHz."
> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/309061/288848

> "You need at least two pins from an MCU to PWM using the L298.
> Applying the PWM signal to the Inhibit/Enable won't work"
> "you need to supply the PWM to the inputs"
> "In terms of PWM frequency, anything above about 50 Hz should work well."
> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/309067/288848

Though, in the [Arduino Motor Shield Rev3 schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino_MotorShield_Rev3-schematic.pdf), it appears that PWM is actually connected to ENA (which is what I'm doing).

Looking at the block diagram, connecting to the IN pins should have the same effect as connecting to the EN pins. The EN pin is connected to both sink and source transistors though the logic gates.

[image: L298N block diagram]

Comment: Yes. It does support PWM ... <<<An external bridge of diodes is required when inductive loads are driven and when the **inputs of the IC are chopped** ; Shottky diodes would be preferred.>>> Until 40 kHz.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, here is a simulation: bridge driving a DC motor.
PWM Duty = 50 %. DC motor + 10 mH serial.
"Full" step 1 V (command) direct/reverse.
See the "big" current pulse when reversing command.
It can be eliminated by good management of the PWM.

[image]